# interact with special combobox using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, listbox

I'm using selenium2 webdriver with firefox.

Usually, when there is a combobox for e.g. months I set a distinct month by `send_keys(monthname)`.

I have a special listbox this time, where I can't simply `send_keys()` to it (not with webdriver nor manually). I'm not a web developer, so I have no idea what the actual difference is. This is the HTML Code of that combobox:

```
<div class="selectArea marke" style="width: 75px; ">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <span class="center">Month</span>
  <span class="selectButton"></span>
  <div class="disabled" style="display: none; "></div>
</div>

<select name="sregisterdmc" id="sregisterdmc" class="marke outtaHere" style="width:75px" multiple="">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  ...more options...
</select>
```

I have no idea how I could set an option here. I found out that I can get all the option values with `.find_elements_by_tag_name()`, but not how I actually set such one now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a click on the `option` element you want selected.

Comment: Thanks. I just had to click on the combobox itself, and then on the option I want.